# STATIC files problem during heroku deployment of Django web app

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy my Django web app but I'm getting some errors. I followed some tutorials but they did not help. Also, I have all the necessary files like `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`. Even I tried to change `STATIC_ROOT` to `staticfiles` and `static` with no avail

```
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_4dca6fca/static'
   Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
   See traceback above for details.
   You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
   Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
   $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
   Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
   Push failed
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',   # added whitenoise
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn portfolio.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `BASE_DIR` variable in `settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```